# Upper case day of week in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata, uppercase

I can get the day of the week from a data but I can't seem to convert to uppercase

This is the statement I'm using:

```
CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS DATE FORMAT 'e4') (CHAR(9))
```

How can I convert this to uppercase?

I've tried wrapping UPPER around each of the elements of the statement but I get errors each time

```
UPPER(CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS DATE FORMAT 'e4') (CHAR(9)))
UPPER(CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS DATE FORMAT 'e4')) (CHAR(9))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it would be possible to fix your current code

```
Upper(Cast(Cast(Current_Date AS FORMAT 'E4') AS CHAR(9)))
```

it's better to switch to

```
To_Char(Current_Date,'DAY')
```

Comment: thanks this is a great help, I've taken your recommendation and switched to your suggestion.